# Why "having" but not "to have"?

Tags: grammar, word-request

Why is "having" written? And not "to have"

> I was so close to having a perfect activity week on my Apple Watch.

Comment: Switch from Past Tense ***was*** to Present Tense ***am***, discard the intensifier ***so***, and the (syntactically, *optional*) preposition-based adverbial element ***close to***. Then you're looking at ***I am having** [fun, a good time, a perfect week,...].* Does that make it easy for you to see why it's not ***I am have fun***?

Comment: ...even more starkly, compare (valid) ***I am writing*** with (invalid) ***I am [to] write***.

Comment: In this sentence, **to** is a preposition and requires an object, and an **-ing** verb form can serve as the object of a preposition.  Consider the opposite of this sentence: "I was so **far away from having** a perfect activity week..." You would never write "far away to have," and you don't write "close to have" either.

Comment: The adjective "close" does not normally license an infinitival clause as complement, though an 'indirect' complement is possible, as in " I was too close to have a panoramic view", where the infinitival is licensed not by "close" but by the "too" that modifies "close".